# likelihood ratio test in R vs Matlab

Tags: r, matlab

I'm newbie in R and I wonder if that is a function in R that performs the likelihood ratio test [like the one in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/lratiotest.html)?

## Matlab

h = lratiotest(uLogL,rLogL,dof,alpha)

I have likelihood of two models, dof, alpha and I simply need the rejection decision H-value. But I don't know how this can be done in R.

Comment: usually via `anova` (but you don't specify degrees of freedom, which actually aren't relevant for a true likelihood ratio test, or alpha level).

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6505/likelihood-ratio-test-in-r

Comment: Thanks@BenBolker  If I'm correct, p-value > alpha , fail to reject H0 at significance level α. So, if we don't specify the alpha we can't obtain the decision H-value? or we can?  sorry if my question is stupid, I'm not familiar with statistic terms.

Comment: `anova` doesn't return the decision, it just returns the p-value.  You would need to extract the p-value from the result and compare it to the critical level yourself in order to make the decision.